# Activity correlation with Azure Application Insights, ASP.NET MVC and NLog

Tags: .net, azure, logging, nlog, azure-application-insights

How do I set up the mix? I have no problems configuring **Application Insights** and **NLog** but I have no idea how to correlate operations. I use latest version of **NLog** so it's aware of `System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId` with its `${activityid}` variable. On the other hand **Application Insights** uses it's own correlation mechanism. My questions are:

1. Who is responsible to initialize standard `Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId`? I thought it was **ASP.NET MVC** but in the debugger it's always `Guid.Empty`. If it's up to me where is the best place in MVC pipeline to generate the id?
2. How to make **Application Insights** use `Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId`? Or, make **NLog** use **Aplication Insights**' internal correlation ID?
3. How to make sure the ID is properly propagated/restored on any `Task.Run()` and `await` calls?

**Update:**

Here is what I ended up with to link AI to NLog:

```
    private void Log(LogEventInfo lei)
    {
        lei.Properties["OperationId"] = CorrelationManager.GetOperationId();
        this.logger.Log(lei);
    }
```

This is wrapper over **NLog**'s `Log()` method which adds a property that can be referenced in NLog.config as `${event-context:OperationId}`. `CorrelationManager` here is the solution from the link provided by @Aravind. The use of system `CallContext` guarantees that operation Ids will flow across all async points. Now, we need to grab **AI** operation id and store it in `CorrelationManager`. This is done in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    RequestTelemetry telemetry = HttpContext.Current.GetRequestTelemetry();
    string operationId = telemetry?.Id ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    CorrelationManager.SetOperationId(operationId);
}
```

Now, If **AI** is enabled for your application your **NLog** log is correlated with **AI** log.

Comment: did you already check this post ? https://dzimchuk.net/post/event-correlation-in-application-insights

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I found it and use as a base for my experiments yet.

Comment: @UserControl I'm in the process of implementing a similar solution for the company I work at, did you eventually find a decent solution? Mind sharing it? Maybe I can contribute a little to it.

Comment: @Mvision, it's still an oped issue but I've updated my question with what I currently use.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Application Insights 2.1+ in your .net core application  (probably .net framework too but I've not tested) they automatically set `System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current` to an object that has all the Application Insights info you could want and more ([ref](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/504)).

Within code you can use `System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current?.Id` or `System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current?.RootId`. (Use the debugger to inspect `Activity.Current` to see what else is there & understand what the different nlog tags will output)

To log it using nlog you use the [NLog.DiagnosticSource package](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.DiagnosticSource):

1. Install the package

   `Install-Package NLog.DiagnosticSource` or in your csproj:

   ```xml
   <PackageReference Include="NLog.DiagnosticSource" Version="1.*" />
   ```
2. Add to your nlog.config:

   ```xml
   <extensions>
       <add assembly="NLog.DiagnosticSource"/>
   </extensions>
   ```
3. Add to an nlog Target:

Use `${activity:property=TraceId}` (or Id instead of TraceId, or one of the [many other properties they list](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.DiagnosticSource)) in a `<target>`, e.g.:

```xml
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.DiagnosticSource"/>
</extensions>
<targets>
    <target name="console" xsi:type="console" layout="${message}|TraceId=${activity:property=TraceId}" />
</targets>
<rules>
    <logger minLevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
</rules>
```

This will output log messages something like:

```
My log message|TraceId=921af8f6ba994c9eb3832ebf200846d7
```

or using `Id` instead of `TraceId`

```
My log message|Id=00-921af8f6ba994c9eb3832ebf200846d7-0e8ba5571915864b-00
```