# Get Corelation Id in .NET core WebAPI using NLog?

Tags: nlog

I'm new to .NET core. How to get the **correlation ID** to log the response using **NLog**?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593801/approach-for-tying-all-nlog-logs-back-to-the-original-request-within-webapi/54854029#54854029 ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `${activityid}` to render System.Diagnostics trace correlation id.

Or if you need `request.GetCorrelationId()`, you could do this:

You could do this:

```cs
// using NLog.Web package

// register as soon as possible
AspNetLayoutRendererBase.Register("myCorrelationId", 
      (logEventInfo, httpContext, loggingConfiguration)
           => httpContext.Request.GetCorrelationId());
```

and render like `${myCorrelationId}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is meant by "CorrelationId" but you can do this with [NLog.Web.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore):

```
layout="${activityid:whenEmpty=${mdlc:item=RequestId:whenEmpty=${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}}}"
```

And if you are using JsNLog then you can do this:

```
layout="${aspnet-request:header=JSNLog-RequestId:whenEmpty=${mdlc:item=RequestId:whenEmpty=${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}}}"
```